# How can I add a label to the cadvisor and node-exporter metrics?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter, cadvisor

My node-exporter metrics are something like:

```
process_cpu_seconds_total{instance="10.1.1.1:8080",job="node_info"}
process_cpu_seconds_total{instance="10.1.1.2:8080",job="node_info"}
process_cpu_seconds_total{instance="10.1.1.15:8080",job="node_info"}
```

The cadvisor ones:

```
container_memory_usage_bytes{id="<id>",image="<image>",instance="10.1.1.1:8080",job="docker_info",name="<container name>"}
container_memory_usage_bytes{id="<id>",image="<image>",instance="10.1.1.3:8080",job="docker_info",name="<container name>"}
container_memory_usage_bytes{id="<id>",image="<image>",instance="10.1.1.16:8080",job="docker_info",name="<container name>"}
```

I want to add a label such as `machine_name`, something like this:

```
process_cpu_seconds_total{machine_name="cool_machine",instance="10.1.1.1:8080",job="node_info"}
container_memory_usage_bytes{machine_name="cool_machine",id="<id>",image="<image>",instance="10.1.1.1:8080",job="docker_info",name="<container name>"}
```

When I try to filter by machine I need to deal with the IP (10.1.1.1), and that is not very user friendly.
I wanted to configure node-exporter and cadvisor to add a label to all metrics, this way I can identify the machine no matter what is the IP they have now.

By the way, changing the DNS so the machine answers in another address is not much of an option for me.

My prometheus config is something like:

```yaml
global:
  scrape_interval: 5s
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'machines_monitor'
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'node_info'
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - 10.1.1.1:8080
          - 10.1.1.2:8080
          - 10.1.1.15:8080
  - job_name: 'docker_info'
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - 10.1.1.1:8080
          - 10.1.1.3:8080
          - 10.1.1.16:8080
```

I can create a `scrape_configs` for machine and start filtering by that but I don't know if that is a good idea, maybe a performance issue with Prometheus.

I'm trying to add labels to the metrics, but I'm other approaches to help to identify the machines are very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following:

```yaml
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'node_info'
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - 10.1.1.1:8080
          - 10.1.1.2:8080
          - 10.1.1.15:8080
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        regex: '10\.1\.1\.1.+'
        replacement: cool_machine_1
        target_label: machine_name
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        regex: '10\.1\.1\.2.+'
        replacement: cool_machine_2
        target_label: machine_name
      ...
```

Comment: How would I do this dynamically based using data from another series? For instance, pull from `hostname` label from the `node_uname_info` series?

Comment: this seems like if you're deploying caadvisor on multiple machines, they will all have the same hostname

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach to add labels to targets defined in `static_configs` section is to use `labels` section - see [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#static_config). For example, the following config would add `machine_name` label to the scraped metrics from the given statically defined targets:

```yaml
scrape_configs:
- job_name: node_info
  static_configs:
  - targets: ['10.1.1.1:9100']
    labels:
      machine_name: cool_machine_1
  - targets: ['10.1.1.2:9100']
    labels:
      machine_name: cool_machine_2
  - targets: ['10.1.1.15:9100']
    labels:
      machine_name: cool_machine_15
- job_name: docker_info
  static_configs:
  - targets: ['10.1.1.1:8080']
    labels:
      machine_name: cool_machine_1
  - targets: ['10.1.1.3:8080']
    labels:
      machine_name: cool_machine_3
  - targets: ['10.1.1.16:8080']
    labels:
      machine_name: cool_machine_16
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, I can use Prometheus `metric_relabel_configs` for that, my config would be something like this:

```yaml
global:
  scrape_interval: 5s
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'machines_monitor'
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'node_info'
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - 10.1.1.1:8080
          - 10.1.1.2:8080
          - 10.1.1.15:8080
    metric_relabel_configs:
      - source_labels:
          - instance
        target_label: instance
        regex: '10\.1\.1\.1(.*)'
        action: replace
        replacement: cool_machine
```

There is a related question:
[Prometheus create label from metric label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775064/prometheus-create-label-from-metric-label)

Here we can see some other examples:
https://gist.github.com/trastle/1aa205354577ef0b329d4b8cc84c674a

Here is a related post:
https://www.robustperception.io/controlling-the-instance-label